# Text inside a rounded rectangle

Tags: tikz-node, tikzpagenodes

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (example-textwidth-3) [draw, align=center, text width=16cm, rounded corners=4]{\vfill \textbf{\LARGE Subject Title \vfill}\\ \vspace{0.5cm} \Large This is a long title. This is a long title. This is a long title. This is a long title. This is a long title. This is a long title. \linebreak};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of my code]

I want to correct the error, and display it centered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Your box is much wider than width of text block, consequently it protrude its right border. In above image box width is limited to width of text:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (example-textwidth-3) [draw, rounded corners,
                                 text width=\linewidth-24pt,    % <---
                                 align=flush center, 
                                 inner sep=12 pt]%
    {\textbf{\LARGE Subject Title}\par
     \vspace{5mm}
     \Large 
     This is a long title. This is a long title. This is a long title. This is a long title. This is a long title. This is a long title};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```